# shared_ptrs and the rule of three

Tags: c++, arraylist, shared-ptr

I am continuing my process of understanding these topics, and I wanted to try to actually use my knowledge on a class that I already had created previously called `ArrayList`, which dynamically allocates memory when the original array created when the class is created gets filled up. This is what (part of) my class looks like: [I guess most of the code itself isn't important, I'm just showing what I have. The main point of the question is after all the code]

And here are the functions that take care of adding elements to the array and reallocating memory when it gets filled up. The append function might look at bit weird because I'm trying to place the elements in ascending order, but that part's not really important.

Now that I've posted that class that took a lot more space than expected, here is my question:

How exactly would I use shared_ptrs with this class? I know that shared_ptrs make it easier to manage my dynamically allocated resources, but would a shared_ptr in this case be used to create the original array, and to delete the old array automatically when the pointer to the array is assigned to the new array? I can see how I would do that, but how would that have any effect on the rule of three [which I read basically is not needed if you use shared_ptrs]. I almost feel like..there are two dimensions to using shared_ptr in this case; one used to actually take care of allocating and deallocating resources for the object itself, but another also if I wanted to create a new object and copy the original object's array into the second object...if this makes sense? I'm guessing to do that I would have

```
ArrayList AL(10);
shared_ptr<ArrayList> ptr = make_shared<ArrayList>(AL);
```

Is this effectively doing the same thing as if I had done

```
ArrayList AL(10);
ArrayList AL2(AL);
```

except that it does the job of the destructor, copy constructor, and copy-assignment operator by itself? Sorry if this was all confusing and long but I'm just...confused.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `std::shared_ptr` in your case. Since there's always only one owner, I'd prefer `std::unique_ptr`. It essentially works the same way, but it won't do the reference counting (since there's always only one owner holding the resource).

You'd no longer have to delete `arr` in your destructor and you'd modify the following lines:

```
delete [] arr;
arr = new int[that.size];
```

to something as simple as this:

```
arr.reset(new int[that.size]);
```

This will free the previous instance (if any) and then take ownership of the new one.

Comment: ...Ahh, I think I see what's going on. I should probably have read the section on unique_ptrs before I actually tried to apply my knowledge..so in this case I would use a unique_ptr, because what I DON'T want is two different objects pointing to the same memory [the array] (which is why I did all the copy control functions). So using unique_ptr would allow for me to not have to use the destructor, and I wouldn't need a copy constructor or copy assignment operator bc unique_ptr would move it for me? @Mario

Comment: You still have to copy your stuff. You just don't have to worry about freeing your memory as that's done for you once you reset the pointer or it goes out of scope.

Comment: Okay, so now I'm just getting confused. Okay, let's say I create my ArrayList object, add stuff to it, etc, and then I want another object with a copy of the array in the original object. If the first object is AL and the second is AL2 and I want initialize it, I would still do ArrayList AL2(AL). So where does the unique_ptr come in? Would it be something like: unique_ptr<ArrayList> ptr(AL2) ? @Mario

Comment: Consider those managed pointers to work just like regular pointers.  Only difference: You don't have to worry about freeing memory.

Comment: Okay...let's say I have a non-member function "void valueAt(ArrayList& obj)"...I pass in an ArrayList object and I have it print the value at position 2 for example...when the object is passed as an argument, the newly created obj now has its pointer pointing to a copy of the original array. And when the function ends, obj goes out of scope and the class destructor frees the memory. How would I re-implement all that using unique_ptr? or could you give me a good example where I could use it? @Mario

Comment: Think you're confusing concepts here, e.g. you're passing a reference, so there won't be a copy and the change to managed pointers won't affect how your class interacts.

Comment: I think I am as well. When I read about the rule of three, several people mentioned that using smart pointers kind of took care of that, because they would do the destructors job for you. So I'm thinking that unique_ptrs have some relation to copying objects, because otherwise, why would that matter? There is a relation between copy control and unique_ptrs, is there not? @Mario

Comment: You can't copy unique pointers. Shared pointers work like references in C#. They have no impact on the values they're pointing at.

Comment: okay...I really don't wanna leave this more confused than when I came in. So in your original answer, what exactly were you doing? You made arr a unique_ptr, but you also changed code in my copy assignment operator. Why? @Mario

Comment: You must not manually free a managed pointer. The call to `arr.reset()` essentially deletes the previous value and then assigns the new one. So both code snippets are essentially the same, one using unmanaged/raw pointers, the other using a unique pointer.